# An entity must belong to only one of the two possible parent entities

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I have three entities

1. Assignment
2. Lecture
3. File

An **Assignment** can have a **File**. A **Lecture** can have a **File** too.
A **File** can be either be related to an **Assignment** or to a **Lecture**, but NOT to both.

How can I express this three way relationship in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to your File table that identifies the type of parent, like a varchar perhaps. More complicated implementations could use a lookup table to get valid values if needed...